# Why is this defined as $u[n]$?

Tags: signal-processing

In LTI systems there are two famous functions the unit step function and the unit impulse functions. And they are defined as follows.
$$ u[n] =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$ $\ge$ 0} \\
0, & \text{if $n$ $\lt$ 0}
\end{cases}
$$
$$ \delta[n] =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$ $=$ 0} \\
0, & \text{if n $\neq$ 0}.
\end{cases}
$$

They also define $u[n]$ as 
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} \delta[k]$$

Isn't this something like $ ... + \delta[-3] + \delta[-2] + \delta[-1] + \delta[0] + \delta[1] + \delta[2] + \delta[3] + ... + \delta[n]$ that gives just one(1)? Because $\delta[n] = 1$ when $n = 0$. How can we say it is a step function?

Comment: $u[-1] = ... + \delta[-2] + \delta[-1] = ...+0+0 = 0$, $u[17] = ... + \delta[-1] + \delta[0] + \delta[1] + ... + \delta[17] = ...+0+1+0+...+0 = 1$.

Comment: Aha now I'm getting it. $u[n]$ doesn't mean a continuous line but a point only. So it makes sense. :)